# How does INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE work?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

Suppose I have a table `STUDENT` with columns including `ID`, `name`, `email`, and `advisorID`. And I have a second table `ADVISOR` with fields including `ID` and `name`. `STUDENT.AdvisorID` is a foreign key. When inserting a student, you must have a key pointing toward an `ADVISOR`.

When inserting a student from the application, however, you only have an `ADVISOR` name. In other words, you have strings with a particular student's name and email, as well as the advisor's name, but not the Advisor ID.

Somehow I just can't get my head wrapped around how to do this. I know it's a common situation, and I've even found one or two similar Q's asked in the past on stackoverflow. I know we're talking about INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM .. WHERE. I assume the WHERE clause is advisor.name='anAdvisorName' but I'm struggling with the fact some of the info getting inserted is from a table and some is not. (Discussions about this kind of statement seem to center on instances where all the data being inserted is from a second table. That's not what I'm talking about.)

p.s. To make it simple, please don't worry about duplicate entries, multiple advisors with the same name, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible way:

```
insert into student (name, email, advisorID)
    values (
        'Fred Smith',
        'fred@example.com',
        (select id from advisor where name = 'Lord Voldemort'))
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't have to use `INSERT INTO SELECT` to do that. You can simply insert `Advison` first, check the `ID` that was assigned and then use it while inserting `Student` entity.

If you'd like to use `INSERT INTO SELECT` anyway, you can do it like that:

```
INSERT INTO Student (name, email, advisorID)
SELECT 'studentName', 'studentEmail', ID
FROM Advisor
WHERE advisorName = 'advisonName'
```

Comment: This is helpful. I've been thinking SELECT statements, in this context, always involved 'selecting' something (from another table). I didn't know one could directly include field values in a SELECT statement. It still seems a bit counterintuitive, but really good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you SELECT you get a table of results, e.g.:

```
mysql> select 'Hello' AS first, 'Everyone' AS second;
+-------+----------+
| first | second   |
+-------+----------+
| Hello | Everyone |
+-------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Those results needn't completely contain data from another table as in this example.

You can put the results of a SELECT directly into another table. E.g.

```
INSERT INTO newtable
    ( first, second )
VALUES
    ( 'Hello', 'Everyone' )
```

which would have the same effect as

```
INSERT INTO newtable
SELECT
    'Hello' AS first,
    'Everyone' AS second
```